# Unit Testing Sharepoint object UserProfileManager

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, sharepoint-2010, typemock

I'm driving crazy here with this exception I'm getting. I'm unit testing a Sharepoint 2010 project with Typemock Isolator and Nunit. What I'm trying to mock is the UserProfile collection for a UserProfileManager.

Code to test:

```
    public void IterateUsers()
    {
        SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site); 
            if (profileManager == null)
            {
                profileManager = new UserProfileManager(context);
            }

            foreach (UserProfile profile in profileManager)
            {
                DoThingsThatAreNotRelevant();
            }

         }
     }
```

And my test code:

```
[Test]
public void IterateUsersTest()
{
    //SPSite
    var fakeSite = Isolate.Fake.Instance<SPSite>(Members.ReturnRecursiveFakes);
    Isolate.Swap.NextInstance<SPSite>().With(fakeSite);

    //SPServiceContext
    var fakeSPServiceContext = Isolate.Fake.Instance<SPServiceContext>  (Members.ReturnRecursiveFakes);
    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => SPServiceContext.GetContext(fakeSite)).WillReturn(fakeSPServiceContext);

    //UserProfileManager
    var fakeUserProfileManager = Isolate.Fake.Instance<UserProfileManager>(Members.ReturnRecursiveFakes);
    Isolate.Swap.NextInstance<UserProfileManager>().With(fakeUserProfileManager);

    //UserProfile
    var fakeUserProfile = Isolate.Fake.Instance<UserProfile>(Members.ReturnRecursiveFakes);
    Isolate.Swap.NextInstance<UserProfile>().With(fakeUserProfile);

    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeUserProfileManager).WillReturnCollectionValuesOf(new[] {fakeUserProfile, fakeUserProfile, fakeUserProfile});
}
```

So, my plan is to mock the UserProfileManager to return a collection of fakeUserProfile so I can iterate through the foreach loop. The content of the fakeUserProfile is not really important since I can mock the behaviour with no problem.

The thing is, when it tries to execute this line

```
 Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeUserProfileManager).WillReturnCollectionValuesOf(new[] {fakeUserProfile, fakeUserProfile, fakeUserProfile});
```

I obtain a nice ArgumentOutOfRangeException. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: According to the [docs](http://docs.typemock.com/isolator/##typemock.chm/Documentation/ReplacingCollectionsAAA.html) the way you do it seems to be correct. Maybe problem lies in the way you create it. Since I never used isolator, I'm afraid I can't help. Fixing tags tho, it might bring proper people's attention.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
 Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeUserProfileManager).WillReturnCollectionValuesOf(new[] {fakeUserProfile, fakeUserProfile, fakeUserProfile});
```

Is wrong! you need to specify a method in order for it to work for example:

```
Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeUserProfileManager.SomeMethod()).WillReturnCollectionValuesOf
```

You cannot tell it to return a value from a fake instance only from specific method on that instance.

Comment: I thought that as well, even when that line is exactly as the one in the documentation so I've tried with this one:  
>     Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeUserProfileManager.GetEnumerator()).WillReturnCollectionValuesOf(new[] { fakeUserProfile, fakeUserProfile, fakeUserProfile });   
      I get a different exception, true, but still not working:  
> Method Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileManagerBase.GetEnumerator returns System.Collections.IEnumerator. Can only use WillReturnCollectionValuesOf() on enumerable types.

Comment: Odd - the error is an error created when you use WillReturn instead of WillReturnCollectionValueOf.  

I guess that's what Typemock support is for :)